# Send a email with a sharepoint link to one address but shows another in the TO field of the email. Is that possible in HTML?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a SharePoint classic page with a link on it. When a user clicks on the link it opens an e-mail client with de address in it. The address i have specified is ABC@xxx.de, but in the TO section of the email it shows DEF@xxx.de.

Is it possible in the html below. To send the email to DEF@xxx.de but displays ABC@xxx.de in the TO section of the e-mail?

SO in other words. In the SharePoint link it shows ABC@xxx.de and sends the email to DEF@xxx.de
Which is good. Because ABC@xxx.de  is an alias of DEF@xxx.de.

But in the To section of the email is shows DEF@xxx.de and it should be displaying ABC@xxx. Is that even possible:

Here is my html:

```
<div class="ms-rteThemeForeColor-2-0" style="text-align: left;"> 
  <span style="font-size: 13px;"><a href="mailto:DEF@xxx.de">ABC@xxx.de</a>&#160;</span></div>
<div class="ms-rteThemeForeColor-2-0" style="text-align: left;"> 
  <span style="font-size: 13px;"></span>&#160;<br/></div>
<div class="ms-rteForeColor-2 ms-rteThemeFontFace-2" style="font-size: 13px; text-align: left;"> 
</div> 
<div class="ms-rteForeColor-2 ms-rteThemeFontFace-2" style="font-size: 13px; text-align: left;"> 
  <br/> 
</div>
<p> 
  <a name="Mail us" title="Mail us" href="mailto:DEF@xxx.de" target="_blank">
```

gr. p

Comment: I don't think so. Whatever email address you use in `mailto:<email-address>` will be shown in `To` section of email when link opens an email client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mailto: does not support displaying one email address while sending to another. You can use a work around to display a different name with the email address:

```
<a href="mailto:DEF@xxx.de">ABC</a>
```

In this case, the email will be sent to DEF@xxx.de, but the link text that is displayed will be ABC.